# Sql server default language list

Tags: sql-server

Can any one give the list of default language and it's code in sql server

e.g:

> sp_configure 'default language', 23

In this example I changed default language to 23 (British).
So I want the list of language (e.g British) and it's code (e.g 23).

Comment: [select * from sys.syslanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [sys.syslanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx).

> Contains one row for each language present in the instance of SQL
>   Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master;

GO

SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages;
```

or

```
USE master;

GO

EXEC SP_HELPLANGUAGE;
```